# Logging outgoing mails in debian? How, where?

Tags: debian, logging, email

I need to see if a php application has sent a bulk mailing.
Would these messages be logged? 
How could I tell whether logging is enabled / how would I set it up

The VPS is running debian.

Any help greatfully received as this is not my area really.

Many Thanks,

Paul

Comment: "Running Debian" isn't nearly enough information for any but the most general of answers.  What MTS is installed?  Notice that your question is missing a "qmail", "postfix", "exim", or "sendmail" tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, your Mail Transfer Agent will log the outgoing messages.  Exim uses log files in `/var/log/exim4`.  Log messages from other MTAs may end up in `/var/log/mail.log`.  This assumes you are using a local MTA to do the delivery for you.

Running the command `mailq` as root may show a bunch of messages pending delivery.  These may include some from the bulk delivery.

If the software does direct delivery, bypassing your MTA then you will need to see if the application has its own log file.